# How do you make a NTFS disk Partition?

Tags: command-line, ntfs, cluster, ntfs-3g

How do you make NTFS file system with the cluster size of 512? Using only the command line?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few `mkfs.*` commands, including `mkfs.ntfs` to create partitions, they support a lot of options, take a look at their manpages.

To create a partition with cluster size of 512:

```
mkfs.ntfs -c 512 /dev/sdXX
```